# Need some help for this Excel issue

Tags: excel

There are two Activities that a user can select. Activity One takes 8 hours to complete. Activity Two takes 12 hours to complete. A variable called selected_option is set to a value of 1 if Activity One is selected and a value of 2 if Activity Two is selected. Create an Excel formula that would result in selecting the correct number of hours based upon which Activity the user selected.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Dang that so sounds like a homework question at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IF` formula to accomplish what you want.

I am assuming your data is as follows:

[image]

Enter following formula in `Cell C2`:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",IF(B2=1,8,IF(B2=2,10,"Incorrect Activity")))
```

Or

```
=IF(B2=1,8,IF(B2=2,10,""))
```

If your data is consistent you can simply use following formula:

```
=IF(B2=1,8,10)
```